# Place multiple icons in each element of list using html

Tags: html, css, web

I would like to have multiple icons shown at the left of each element, having the choice to place many or none, if y'all could point me to the right direction.

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <a href="http://localhost:4000/">
        <li class=" current btn-nav ">Blog</li>
      </a>
      <a href="http://localhost:4000/Projects">
        <li class=" btn-nav ">Projects</li>
      </a>
      <a href="http://localhost:4000/About">
        <li class=" btn-nav ">About</li>
      </a>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
.nav-list {
  display: grid;
}

.btn-nav::before {
  content: "";
}
/* unicode for other symbols can be copied from here */

  <header>
    <nav>
      <div class="nav-list">
        <span class="btn-nav">
          <a href="http://localhost:4000/">
            Blog
          </a>
        </span>
        <span class="btn-nav">
          <a href="http://localhost:4000/Projects">
            Projects
          </a>
        </span>
        <span class="btn-nav">
          <a href="http://localhost:4000/About">
            About
          </a>
        </span>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>
```

You can use ::before css selector to add content before HTML element.
[Working Link](https://web-platform-vj5ysz.stackblitz.io)

Answer (score 0):

You have https://fontawesome.com/, it's a library of icons. It's free.

And you can put this, for example it's an arrow:

```
<a href="http://localhost:4000/">
<i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i>
        <li class=" current btn-nav ">Blog</li>
      </a>
```

After, you style with css.

I hope to help you.